# react.js useState is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use react with links but `useState` is not defined

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/babel">
function App() {
  const [name , setName] = useState('ali');
  const handelClick = () => {
    setName('mahdi')
  }
  return (
  <div className="continer">
    <header>
      <Navbar />
    </header>
    <div className="test">
      <div>{name}</div>
      <button type="button" name="button" onClick={handelClick}> click </button>
    </div>
    <div className="content">
      <Business />
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}

//render components
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

</script>
```

Comment: First you have to import it : "import {useState} from "react"

Comment: You have to use it from the `React` object, usually by destructuring at the top of your code: `const { useState } = React;`

Comment: @klaus_bathory - Given the content of the script tags above, they don't appear to be using modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you use CDN, you must use it as property of object `React` like this:

```js
//...

const [name , setName] = React.useState('ali');

//...
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to take it from the global React object.

```
const { useState } = React;
function App() {
  // ...
```

Same sort of thing for all other hooks.

You also might want to change `handelClick` to `handleClick` to avoid confusing yourself.

Comment: Surely that click handler is for playing the *Messiah*. ;-)

Comment: This doesn't work. Debugging the React factory I can see that it checks if `enableHooks` is truthy and only adds the hooks to the `React` object if it is. It is set to `false` earlier on in the script. How is one supposed to enable it?

Comment: @steinybot It sounds like the code you're using is pretty different from the code in the question here, in which case my answer obviously wouldn't be appropriate for your situation. If you have a different question, post it as a question rather than downvoting and asking something different as a comment.

Comment: My code wasn't very different except that it specified a version of React < 16.8.0 (that was the choice in the SO code snippet editor). I initially thought that your answer was incomplete for the browser but it was because hooks were hidden behind the `enableHooks` flag. SO won't let me remove my down vote.

Answer (score 0):

If you encountered this problem trying to create a code snippet in StackOverflow like I did then part of the problem is that the latest version in the dropdown at the time of writing is 16.6.3.

The hooks were added in 16.6.1 but they were behind a feature flag and not enabled by default until [16.8.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1680-february-6-2019).

So using:

```js
const { useState } = React;
```

or:

```js
React.useState(...)
```

alone will not solve the problem.

Make sure to also use a version >= 16.8.0.